# Coinjoin in Bitcoin Core wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, coinjoin

I was reading this quesion: [How to properly combine PSBTs for CoinJoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/93138/how-to-properly-combine-psbts-for-coinjoin)

And Bitcoin Core issues:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/6568

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/3226

Everything looks easy except coordinator part or creating a liquidity pool like joinmarket which is decentralized.

What are the possible options to solve this problem using Bitcoin tech which may or may not be acceptable to Bitcoin Core maintainers and contributors? Can LN solve this or is it possible using Simplicity with Elements or solidity code with Rootstock involved? Or is it easier and Bitcoin scripting right now or after Taproot is good enough to solve this problem? Even if the solution is not completely decentralized but minimizes trust it should improve things. For example: if it requires using oracles maybe we can use DLC

Comment: How do you expect script system changes to help with coordination? Coinjoin operates at a different level - it's aggregating inputs, not scripts. The problem is finding people to aggregate with.

Comment: `1` Joinmarket uses IRC for messaging channels right now: https://github.com/JoinMarket-Org/joinmarket-clientserver/blob/master/docs/config-irc-update.md, still not able to find a decentralized solution for automated market making: https://github.com/JoinMarket-Org/joinmarket-clientserver/issues/415 `2` Wasabi and Samourai have centralized coordinators earning fees instead of maker taker model. So I think we need smart contract which can coordinate the coinjoins. People can interact with it using bitcoin core, provide liquidity, check info, do coinjoin etc.