# Can multiple wallets send 1 transaction for the combined balance?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I have multiple wallets, I want to transfer all of the money to 1 wallet of some other person. But I want to do this as one transaction to avoid fees. Is this possible with bitcoind API?

Comment: For programmers interested in the underlying technical question here (unrelated to BitcoinD service), the Bitcoin protocol itself is capable of making a transaction from multiple inputs of different wallets according to this answer here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/51687/4325 --- I have not verified this claim, am just sharing for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a wallet which supports importing private keys, such an Bitcoin Core, you can just import the private key of your other wallet: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5944/14325